# Is there a better way to populate hierarchical data from SQL into a class structure, C# or VB.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to populate hierarchical data in a .NET 2.0 (yes, 2.0) application and upgrading right now is off the table (so no LINQ, LINQ Bridge, or other things).

I was wondering if there is a better way to populate hierarchical data into this class structure?  I'm pretty sure there is a far better way for this to be accomplished.

It would be really nice to see a good way to do this.  If anyone has the time to show a .NET 2.0 way and if there is a different way they would do it in .NET 4.0+ that would be great.

Here is an example of the node type structure:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ExampleNode
{

private int _id;

private Nullable<int> _parentId;


private int _depth;

private List<ExampleNode> _children = new List<ExampleNode>();

public ExampleNode()
{
}

public virtual int ApplicationNumber {
    get { return _id; }
    set { _id = value; }
}

public virtual Nullable<int> ParentId {
    get { return _parentId; }
    set { _parentId = value; }
}


public virtual int Depth {
    get { return _depth; }
    set { _depth = value; }
}


public virtual List<ExampleNode> Children {
    get { return _children; }
    set { _children = value; }
}
}
```

Here is an example function that is being utilized to populate the node structure.  It seems like it is not the best way to do this and it has the potential not to populate grandchildren type data.  Depth comes back from the stored proc as the level in the hierarchy (items with a level of 0 are top level, if a node is the child of a top level node it is at level 1, a grandchild of a top level node is level 2, etc.)

```
public List<ExampleNode> GetNodes()
{
// This may not be optimal.

List<ExampleNode> nodeList = new List<ExampleNode>();
Dictionary<int, ExampleNode> nodeDictionary = new Dictionary<int, ExampleNode>();

using (SqlDataReader reader = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SqlServer").ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "proc_GetNodeStructure", new SqlParameter("@UserId", userId), new SqlParameter("@NodeTypeId", nodeType))) {
    while (reader.Read) {
        ExampleNode nodeInstance = new ExampleNode();

        nodeInstance.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader("Id"));
        nodeInstance.Depth = Convert.ToInt32(reader("Depth"));


        if (!Information.IsDBNull(reader("ParentId"))) {
            nodeInstance.ParentId = Convert.ToInt64(reader("ParentId"));
        }

        // Add to list
        nodeList.Add(nodeInstance);

        // Add to dictionary
        nodeDictionary.Add(nodeInstance.Id, nodeInstance);

    }
}

foreach (ExampleNode item in nodeList) {
    if (item.ParentId.HasValue) {
        nodeDictionary(item.ParentId).Children.Add(item);
    }

}

for (int i = nodeList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i += -1) {
    if (nodeList(i).Depth > 0) {
        nodeList.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}

return nodeList;
}
```

Comment: I don't know that many people would consider moving to LINQ an "upgrade."

Comment: Do you have to use a data reader? I was thinking if you can use a data table and use it in a recursive function, get the root nodes first (`ParentId IS NULL`), then get the children based on the parent id value (`ParentId = <current node id>`), etc. With `LINQ` you have much more flexibility, but you cannot use it if you are constrained to use `.NET 2.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you

1. gather the nodes into a list and a dictionary
2. iterate through the list and arrange parent/child relationships via the dictionary
3. remove nodes from the list that have a positive depth

... which leaves the list containing the top-most nodes in the hierarchical stucture.  Your algorithm seems correct to me.

The first two operations are O(n) complexity in time and space with respect to the number of nodes, which is pretty good!

The only real inefficient thing you are doing is removing elements from the list in step 3.  Because the underlying storage is a vector, removing an element from the front of the list is expensive, because all of the remaining elements need to be copied down.  You are trying to minimize the amount of such copying by iterating over the list backward.  Imagine that the last half of the list is parent nodes, and the front half is child nodes.  Whenever you remove a child node, you will still have to copy half the original list size every time a child node is removed.  This approaches O(n^2) behaviour.

So for step 3 you have at least two choices if you wish to improve performance in time:

1. Make a second list that contains only the elements from the first where the depth == 0.
2. Use a linked list instead, so that deletions are O(1) instead of up to O(n) performance.

Here is the code for the first option:

```
...

List<ExampleNode> roots = new List<ExampleNode>();
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.Count; i ++) { 
    if (nodeList[i].Depth == 0) { 
        roots.Add(nodeList[i]);
    }
} 
return roots;
```

You could potentially save even a little more time by counting how many root nodes there are during step 1 or 2, and then initializing the second list so its capacity is equal to the number of root nodes.  This will prevent unnecessary allocations and copying of the underlying list vector while you are adding elements to the list.

```
List<ExampleNode> roots = new List<ExampleNode>(rootCount);
```

The same applies to the first `nodeList`; you can delay its construction until you know the number of records returned from the query.

Comment: Thanks so much Monroe!  This is the feedback/advice I needed.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

What about using [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx)? It works with .net 2 plus, so you can move forward with it as well.